# Rails month localize helper does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization, activesupport

I want to make the translation into Russian of months.
config/locales/ru.yml

```
ru:
  date:
    formats:
      default: "%d-%m-%Y"
      short: "%b %d"
      long: "%B %d, %Y"

    day_names: [Воскресенье, Понедельник, Вторник, Среда, Четверг, Пятница, Суббота]
    abbr_day_names: [Вос, Пон, Вт, Ср, Чет, Пят, Суб]

    month_names: [~, Январь, Февраль, Март, Апрель, Маи, Июнь, Июль, Август, Сентябрь, Октябрь, Ноябрь, Декабрь]
    abbr_month_names: [~, Янв, Фев, Мар, Апр, Маи, Июн, Июл, Авг, Сен, Окт, Ноя, Дек]
  time:
    formats:
      default: "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"
      short: "%d %B %H:%M"
      long: "%B %d, %Y %H:%M"
```

In the view:

```
time now: <%= l Time.now, :format => :short %>
```

Return:

```
time now: 31 l 13:13
```

Current locale is "ru".

```
<%= I18n.locale %>
```

Return:

```
ru
```

Also checked the localization of days by '%a', does not work either. Why localization of months and days of not working?

---

Found duplicate field date in the file location. Removed, the problem persists.